# How to splice two 7 pin SATA cables to make a female-to-female extension cable?

Tags: sata

I can't find any female-to-female adapters for 7 pin SATA cables. Basically, I am building a Star Trek original series themed workstation, most of it is completed. I'm currently working on a table-top unit similar in design to those seen in the TV show that will be the control panel for the workstation.

In it will be a hub that contains storage card readers, usb ports, and sata ports (this would normally be fitted in a DVD-ROM bay in a normal CPU case). Naturally the cables are too short so I'm sorting out extensions for everything.

What I need is a female-to-female adapters for 7 pin SATA adapter so that I can connect an additional SATA cable to create the needed length.

Is it possible to cut a couple of cables and join them to create the female to female adapter that I need? What would the wiring arrangement be?

Comment: how long does it need to be? I'm seeing sata cables on Newegg as long as 6'

Comment: thanks I'll check. I'm in Thailand, not all shops ship here